# Missing Plant on PvZ2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I already unlocked the corn plant but when I re-logged in on my account, it was like this.
I tried finishing Level 1 again but it's not working. It's also missing in the Almanac.
I don't know what happened, but I want my corn plant back. It's on Dead Man's Booty though, but it doesn't appear on any other level.

[image: What?!]

[image]

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Comment: I think it is, I need a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try "restore purchases" from the main menu -- it's a longshot, but possibly that could shake it loose.

If not, sadly you may have to start over as a new user. I couldn't imagine playing without the kernelpults.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried restoring but nothing changed. It said "0 purchases restored".